# Would it be possible to power an X-Ray tube using a Marx generator?

Tags: transformer, x-rays

To the best of my knowledge most X-Ray tubes are powered by a smaller voltage running through a large transformer to step it up into the magnitude of 10-100 KV. This larger voltage is then pulsed through the tube to be picked up by some sensor/film. Is it possible to use this same method, but power it using a system like a Marx generator? Would the current output of the Generator be too low, or the pulse too short?

Comment: Most x-ray systems that I have designed operate using a DC voltage to the tube. The originating power is from a low voltage DC source and is converted to high frequency AC (typically 50 kHz) and used to produce around 5,000 volts RMS (using a ferrite transformer) from which it is DC stepped up to tens of kV using a Cockcroft Walton multiplier bathed in oil or fully encapsulated. Earlier ones used 50 Hz and an oil immersed step-up transformer and a rectifier. So, given that this is a typical and common application, how could the pulse output from a Marx generator be useful?

Comment: Dental X-Ray power supplies might use up to 100kV @ 1kW regulated by up to 5A filament current. I suspect any compact multiplier would not be able to handle this power unless it was just a doubler or tripler after a transformer, but your power requirements may be lower.

Comment: @Andyaka i wasnt exactly sure what sort of systems Xray tubes use; i cant seem to find a lot of information on the web. Since you state you have designed such tube power devices, is there any links or resources you could give me so that i can learn more about the power supplies for these tubes? I have a Canon D-205B tube and all of the housing, but no way to power it.

Comment: [Genvolt industrial power supplies for x-ray applications](https://www.genvolt.com/applications/51474d7ec627d/Industrial-Xray-Power-Supplies) and also this [Genvolt link](https://www.genvolt.com/applications/51474d7ec627d/Industrial-Xray-Power-Supplies?type=X-Ray+Generator+Power+Supply)

Comment: https://emd-technologies.com/ may also provide useful information.

Comment: I don't see why a Marx shouldn't be able to provide a short pulse of high voltage to an x-ray tube. Though it will only be a short pulse, so not much output. It will also be a decaying output, so a range of x-ray energies.